# Timefield [entityform:field-name:value_formatted] token not working in Rules

Tags: 7, entities, tokens

I am having troubles using token replacement for the `Time field` field type provided by the module [Timefield](https://www.drupal.org/project/timefield)  in Rules.

The **token pattern** `[entityform:field-name:value]` works just fine (it gets replaced by the raw "offset value" of the field - I'm using this field in an Entityform), but I just can't figure out how to display the **formatted value**.

I've followed directions in the pattern replacement help text, and tried different combinations of hyphens and low hyphens to no avail: `[entityform:field-name:value_formatted]`, `[entityform:field_name:value_formatted]` and `[entityform:field-name:value-formatted]` - none work.

I've already posted a request for support in the Timefield issue queue, but was wondering if anyone here has had a similar issue, and can point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** After some additional testing, I've discovered that the `[entityform:field_name:value_formatted]` token DOES work in some situations, such as inside a Rules **Component**. It does NOT work if the Rule is triggered by the event `After saving new content`(for nodes) or `After saving a new entityform submission` (for Entityforms). Obviously this seems to be a bug, but I don't have the time to figure out where this problem happens. Apparently the `value` token of the field is built right away, but the `value_formatted` is not readily available when the Rule is triggered right after creating a new entity. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this problem seems to be a bug, and just in case someone else runs into this issue, there is a workaround you can do within Rules to get the formatted value of the time field. It involves:

1. Enable the module **PHP filter**
2. Use the action `Execute custom PHP code` to run a PHP snippet that calculates
   the formatted value using the raw value provided by the token